# Show that limit converges to 0. What happens if f is not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Let $f : [0, 1] → \Bbb R$ be continuous. Show that $\int_0^1x^n f(x) \to 0$.
We can easily prove it assuming $f$ is continuous. Now, what happens we not assume $f$ to be continuous?
I guess then $\int_0^1x^n f(x)$ need not converge to $0$.

One example I think will work is $f$ defined piecewise as follows

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x^{n+1}} & x \in \left[\frac{1}{n + 1}, \frac{1}{n}\right), \\ 0 & x \in \{0, 1\}.\end{cases}$$

Do you think my guess is right or please correct me where I made wrong assumption or provide me with easier example

Comment: You are using the letter $n$ with two different meanings. Besides you did not say why the integral does not tend to $0$ in your example.

Comment: I think your function gets dragged down to 0 eventually? At least pointwise

Comment: If $f$ is integrable then the quantity converges to zero.

Comment: I don't think you can define $f$ using $n$. What you can do is choose a function $f$ that explodes faster than any polynomial at 0, say $f(x)=e^{1/x}$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your example works. In fact, no Riemann integrable $f$ will work. A proof is below.

---

Let $f$ be any Riemann integrable function. Then, $g := |f|$ is bounded, by say, $M$.

I will show that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^n g(x) \ {\mathrm d}x \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Clearly, this implies the same for $f$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Pick $h \in (0, 1)$ such that $$\int_h^1 g < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
(Why must such an $h$ exist?)

Note that $0 \le x^ng(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in [h, 1]$ and thus, $$\int_h^1 x^n g(x)\ {\mathrm d}x \le \int_h^1 g(x)\ {\mathrm d}x < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
for *all* $n \ge 1$.

On the other hand, note that $h^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Pick $N$ large so that $h^nM < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $n > N$. Then, for all $n > N$, we have

$$\int_0^h x^ng(x)\ {\mathrm d}x \le \int_0^h h^n M\ {\mathrm d}x = h^{n + 1} M < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Thus, for all $n > N$, we have
$$0 \le \int_0^1 x^n g(x) \ {\mathrm d}x < \epsilon$$
and hence, we are done.

Comment: If you aren't sure about the existence of $h$. Note that $h = 1 - \epsilon/4M$ will work if $\epsilon < 4M$ (and you can assume that so is the case).